# Как заинжектить вьюмодели компоузаблов даггером2 ? (НЕ хилт)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2, android-jetpack-compose, mvvm-android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заинжектить вьюмодели компоузаблов даггером2 ? (НЕ хилт)